# Using hideshow with Perl code / POD

Tags: code-folding, hideshow, perl

I've got emacs' HideShow mode working well with Perl code (let's face it, it's a doddle), but I don't know if it's even possible to get it to fold POD comments as well. Has anyone done this (and if so, how, please)?

(Note: when asked about this on stackoverflow I was encouraged to ask over here.  Sorry for the dup' thus caused.)

Comment: Welcome to the Emacs StackExchange! Please note that [cross-posting is generally frowned upon](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info), so since you have asked your question here, you should probably [delete your duplicate question on Stack Overflow](//emacs.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions). (I agree that the question is a better fit for this site than for SO.)

Comment: Yes, I've done that now.  It's a shame, I think, that deleting means just that.  It might be more helpful in cases like this to instead mark it as a duplicate of (for example) that post and cross reference it, so that anyone searching for something similar over there gets pointed to this post.

Comment: Yeah. One thing that can help is the [migration feature](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/269535), but unfortunately Emacs.SE is not in the target list, so only a moderator may migrate questions here.